# Inheritance and templates instanciations with pointers to simulate "virtual data"

Tags: c++

I have a hierarchy of classes:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base():a{5}{}
    virtual ~Base(){};
    int a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived():b{10}{}
    int b;
};
```

I then have a class template that operates on whatever type it is instanciated with:

```
template<typename T>
class DoStuff
{
public:
    DoStuff():val{}{}
    virtual ~DoStuff(){};
    virtual void printDoStuff() = 0;
    T getVal(){return val;};
private:
    T val;
};

class DoStuffWithInt : public DoStuff<int>
{
public:
    virtual void printDoStuff() override {cout << "val = " << getVal() << endl;}
};

class DoStuffWithBase : public DoStuff<Base>
{
public:
    virtual void printDoStuff() {cout << "a = " << getVal().a << endl;}
};
```

Now I would like to have a hierarchy of class like this:

```
class DoStuffWithBase : public DoStuff<Base>
{
public:
    virtual void printDoStuff() {printVal(); cout << "a = " << getVal().a << endl;}
};

// Wrong and will not compile, trying to make a point
class DoStuffWithDerived : public DoStuffWithBase<Derived>
{
public:
    void printDoStuff() override {DoStuffWithBase::printDoStuff(); cout << "b = " << getVal().b << endl;}
};
```

Basically I would like to have DoStuffWithBase that operates on a base be extended so that I can reuse its functions, but the extended class DoStuffWithDerived should operate on a Derived type.

I managed to get something working by templating DoStuffWithBase with a pointer to Base and extending it:

```
template <class T>
static void deleteIfPointer(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << "not pointer" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
static void deleteIfPointer(T* t)
//                           ^
{
    std::cout << "is pointer" << std::endl;
    delete t;
}

template<typename T>
class DoStuff
{
public:
    DoStuff():val{}{}
    DoStuff(const T& value):val{value}{};
    virtual ~DoStuff(){deleteIfPointer(val);}
    virtual void printDoStuff() = 0;
    T getVal(){return val;};
private:
    T val;
};

class DoStuffWithBase : public DoStuff<Base*>
{
public:
    // New base
    DoStuffWithBase(): DoStuff(new Base()){}
    DoStuffWithBase(Base* b) : DoStuff(b){}
    virtual void printDoStuff() {printVal(); cout << "a = " << getVal()->a << endl;}
};

class DoStuffWithDerived : public DoStuffWithBase
{
public:
    // New derived
    DoStuffWithDerived(): DoStuffWithBase(new Derived()){}
    void printDoStuff() override {DoStuffWithBase::printDoStuff(); cout << "b = " << static_cast<Derived*>(getVal())->b << endl;}
};
```

It works but there are several things I don't like:

1. The code is a lot more complicated, when 99% of the time, I won't need to extend a DoStuffWithX class, I will just use DoStuffWithInt, DoStuffWithClass, DoStuffWithAnotherClass etc... Here I had to add several constructors, a special case destructor and so on.
2. I have to use pointers and manage them (static_cast when needed, deletion...), all in order to avoid slicing and get the right type. Also, DoStuff::val should theorically not be null, but with a pointer there is no way I can prevent that (or atleast I don't know one). Maybe using smart pointers would help a bit here ? I am not super familiar with them.
3. I have to manage cases where T is a pointer and when it is not. For example, the deleteIfPointer function above, but also switching between . and -> and probably more.

Is there any simpler way to achieve what I am trying to do ? A design pattern or something else ? Am I stuck with my solution and is it somewhat good ?

Edit: I tried to implement it with std::variant as in @Tiger4Hire's answer:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived():b{10}{}
    int b;
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2():c{12}{}
    int c;
};

using DerivedTypes = std::variant<Derived, Derived2>;

struct VariantVisitor
{
    void operator()(Derived& d)
    {
        d.b = 17;
    }

    void operator()(Derived2& d)
    {
        d.c = 17;
    }
};

class DoStuffWithVariant : public DoStuff<DerivedTypes>
{
public:
    void handleBasePart(Base& base)
    {
        cout << "a = " << base.a << endl;
        base.a = 10;
    }

    virtual void printDoStuff() override
    {
        auto unionVal_l = getVal();

        if (std::holds_alternative<Derived>(unionVal_l))
        {
            std::cout << "the variant holds a Derived!\n";
            auto& derived_l = std::get<0>(unionVal_l);
            cout << "b = " << derived_l.b << endl;
            handleBasePart(derived_l);
        }
        else if (std::holds_alternative<Derived2>(unionVal_l))
        {
            std::cout << "the variant holds a Derived2!\n";
            auto& derived2_l = std::get<1>(unionVal_l);
            cout << "c = " << derived2_l.c << endl;
            handleBasePart(derived2_l);
        }
        std::visit(VariantVisitor{}, unionVal_l);
    }
};
```

What I like about it:

1. I don't have to use pointers.
2. I feel the code is less tricky, easier to understand.

What I don't like about it:

1. The code is all in one place and it deals with all the possible Derived types (and even the Base type) at once whereas with inheritance, classes are more specialized, you can really look at a class and directly know what it does, what it overrides etc... On the other hand one could argue that it means the algorithm is in one place instead of dispatched all over the classes hierarchy.
2. You can't have an abstract base class as your interface.

All in all it is a really good alternative, but I am still wondering if there is a simpler way to implement dynamic polymorphism ? Do you necessarily have to resort to (base class) pointers with dynamic polymorphism ? Are std::variant the way to go now ?

Edit2: 2 other drawbacks with variants that I didn't notice at first:

1. All your derived class and your base class have to be defined in the same library. Clients can't easily add a new Derived class since it would mean modifying the variant and they might not have access to it.
   On the project I am working on, base classes are defined in one library, and are derived in other independant "sub" libraries. So if I try to use variant in my main library, it won't be able to access the Derived types in the sub libraries, which is a major issue.
2. If your base class implenting the variant (DoStuff here) has other members, when you call std::visit on the variant, you might have to also embark the needed other members of DoStuff. I think you should be able to use lambdas to capture them, but still, it's a lot less straightforward than using them directly as in the case of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Your core problem is that you cast away your type information.
C++ will always call the right function, if it knows the correct type. This is why the pattern of pointer-to-base is almost always an anti-pattern (even though it is often taught as the "C++" way to do things).
Modern C++-style is to hold things as strongly-typed pointers, and cast them to the base pointer object, only when calling a function that takes a base-pointer as a parameter.
The standard supports this way of working by providing std::variant. Thus rather than

```
   std::vector<Base*> my_list_of_things;
   my_list_of_things.push_back(new Derived); // casting away type is bad
```

You start with

```
   using DerivedTypes = std::variant<std::unique_ptr<Derived1>,
                                     std::unique_ptr<Derived2>/*,etc*/>;
   std::vector<DerivedTypes> my_list_of_things;
```

Now you can iterate over the list, calling a function which takes a pointer-to-base, casting away the type information only during the call.
You can also [visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) the members of the list, with a function (often a lambda) that knows exactly the type it is working on.
So you get the best of both worlds!
This does assume you have access to C++17 or above though, also that you are not working with code that is a library (compiled) but allows the library user to make their own classes. For example, libraries like Qt can't use this way of working.
If you don't have access to C++17, you may find [curiously recursing templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) fit much of what you are doing. (This is a controversial pattern though, as it is ugly and confusing)

Comment: I disagree with `pattern of pointer-to-base is almost always an anti-pattern`. This is how dynamic polymorphism works, and it is as useful now as it was before. But, a client of `my_list_of_things` should only use `virtual` functions defined in `Base` and overridden in `Derived` - which was not the case in the OP example.

Comment: I had to learn how variants work, and I edited my post with a possible implementation. I do have access to c++17. I will look at CRTP as well. Would you say that std::variant is the better alternative to dynamic polymorphism as of c++17 ? Or does it really depends on the situation ?

Comment: @Eugene Why should the client only use virtual functions defined in `Base` and overridden in `Derived` ? Since `my_list_of_things` contains Derived types, it should be able to call the Base's functions, virtual or not ?

Comment: Yes, sure, using non-virtual Base functions is ok. My emphasis was not directly using members specific to derived classes.

Comment: @Eugene Even if I wanted to use the Base part of a virtual function, I could directly call Base::function  from a derived object if I wanted to use only the Base part of the function; or have the derived function call the Base function as in the OP if I wanted to use both the Base and Derived parts right ?

Comment: @Eugene https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_ij0YNkFUs&t=220s. Around 40 minutes in. The world has changed! C++ has changed!

Comment: @PrOpoLo
I don't say this Stroustrup (inventor of C++) says this, in the video in my last comment